# How import an enum in interface angular 4

Tags: angular, enums, interface

Hi everyone now I have one problem with an interface in angular 4.
I have this come on my enum:

```
 export enum Test{
    Test0 =0,
    Test1 =1,
    Test2 =2,
    Test3 =3
    }
```

and in my interface this:

```
import {Test} from './test';
 interface TestInterface {
   value1:string,
   value2: number,
    Test: Test
}
```

Sends me an error like "TestInterface doesn't exists" when I try to extend it

```
interface Grid extends TestInterface {
    template;
}
```

Is it right?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: What is your problem / question? (why are you asking this). On a side note I would recommend you stay consistent in your naming convention. Types in Pascal and properties/variables in camel casing. So `interface TestInterface` and `test: Test` as the field/property.

Comment: @Igor sends me an error like "testInterface doesn't exists"

Comment: `testInterface doesn't exists` <= what does and where. Context is important in a question.

Comment: Sends me an error like "TestInterface doesn't exists" when I try to use

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please, visit [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to use the interface, you need to export it:

```
import {Test} from './test';
 export interface TestInterface {    // <- Notice the export keyword here.
   value1:string,
   value2: number,
    Test: Test
}
```